# Correct direction of coconut tail

Tags: belief, rituals, worship, puja, aarti

I belong to south part of Bharat where the coconut tail is kept in reverse direction of God (or towards us) and then it is burst/chip.

[image]

In Maharashtra in one of the temple when I tried to do the same they told me to hold the coconut tail towards God.

[image]

Ideally what is the correct way? Is there any shloka/mantra which provides the details?

Comment: You mean keeping coconut during puja, before breaking it for naivedhya?

Comment: Nope, I mean while breaking it, when we break it.

Comment: Ok, never heard this before in Karnataka or Tamil Nadu temples.